# responsive grid using display table and float

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/5adjhd1x/2/

How can I make below dialpad responsive? I tried to use width 33% and some JS in demo 1 : http://jsfiddle.net/5adjhd1x/, but I couldn't have margin for them.

```css
.key {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
    border-radius:50%;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align: center;
    display:table;
    margin:1%;
}
.key > span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.clearFloat {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyWrap">
    <div class="key"><span>1</span>

    </div>
    <div class="key"><span>2</span>

    </div>
    <div class="key"><span>3</span>

    </div>
    <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    <div class="key"><span>4</span>

    </div>
    <div class="key"><span>5</span>

    </div>
    <div class="key"><span>6</span>

    </div>
    <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    <div class="key"><span>7</span>

    </div>
    <div class="key"><span>8</span>

    </div>
    <div class="key"><span>9</span>

    </div>
    <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    <div class="key"><span>0</span>

    </div>
    <div class="key dlt"><span>Del</span>

    </div>
</div>
    
    <br>    <br>
```

How can I make them to have margin in percentage and responsive?

Comment: You are doing like this(1% + 33% +1%) for each circle. So the width will be > 100% when you apply the `margin:1%`. As a result, the third circle will be shown on next line.

Comment: @RLam yeah I know the problem but i don't know what's the percentage to put to full fill the screen when the margin is 1%.

Comment: So there will be total 6% margin on each line. You may set your `.key`'s`width` to 31%. Like this [http://jsfiddle.net/932oqw2m/](http://jsfiddle.net/932oqw2m/)

Comment: to fill everything u need 33.33%, how u get the 31%? what should be the width if the margin is 2% or 3%? how u do the calculation?

Comment: 31.33% + `margin-left:1%` + `margin-right:1%` = 33.33% width.

Comment: 3 item in a row. If `margin:2%` for each item, so the width of the item should be `33%-2%-2%` = `29%`. `Margin` is something like spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Answer at here dude:

http://jsfiddle.net/5adjhd1x/6/

Give me a like !

```
.key {overflow: hidden; display: block; background: grey; padding: 0;}
.key li {width: 32%; margin-right: 2%; margin-bottom: 10px; float: left; display: inline-block; background: red;}
.key li:nth-child(3n) {margin-right: 0%;}
```

Comment: slow, i alrdy sloved.